# Cakephp save data and read MAX

Tags: cakephp, save, max

I'm trying to save data in CakePHP in this way:

1. get max entry_id from table translations

   ```
   (SELECT MAX(entry_id) as res FROM translations) + 1
   ```
2. save data into translations table

   ```
   $translationData = array('entry_id' => $entry_id, 'language_id' => $key, 'text' => $item);
   $translation = new Translation();
   $translation->set($translationData);
   $translation->save();
   ```
3. again get max `entry_id`
4. save next set of data
5. again get max `entry_id`
6. save next set of data

Please have a look at my code:

```
    $this->request->data['Product']['name_tr_id'] = $this->Translation->saveTranslations($this->request->data['Product']['name']);
    $this->request->data['Product']['description_tr_id'] = $this->Translation->saveTranslations($this->request->data['Product']['description']);
    $this->request->data['Product']['seo_title_tr_id'] = $this->Translation->saveTranslations($this->request->data['Product']['seo_title']);
    $this->request->data['Product']['seo_keywords_tr_id'] = $this->Translation->saveTranslations($this->request->data['Product']['seo_keywords']);
    $this->request->data['Product']['seo_desc_tr_id'] = $this->Translation->saveTranslations($this->request->data['Product']['seo_desc']);
```

saveTranslations method:

```
public function saveTranslations($data) {
    $entry_id = $this->getNextFreeId();

    foreach($data as $key => $item) {
        if($item != "") {
            $this->create();
            $temp['Translation']['entry_id'] = $entry_id;
            $temp['Translation']['language_id'] = $key;
            $temp['Translation']['text'] = $item;
            $this->save($temp);
        }
    }
    return $entry_id;
}
```

getNextFreeId method:

```
public function getNextFreeId() {
    $result = $this->query("SELECT MAX(entry_id) as res FROM translations");
    return $result[0][0]['res'] + 1;
}
```

I don't know why `entry_id` have all the time the same value.

Comment: Have a look http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-create-array-data-array

Comment: Side note: Never instantiate models like `new Model()`, use `ClassRegistry::init()`, `Controller::loadModel()`, or define the models to load in `Controller::$uses`.

Comment: create method doesn't help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of searching for solution I finally managed to solve the problem in very easy way - just add **false** parameter in query method:

```
$this->query("INSERT INTO translations(entry_id, language_id, text) VALUES($entry_id, $key, '$item')", false);
```

and

```
$result = $this->query("SELECT SQL_CACHE MAX(entry_id) as res FROM translations", false);
```